# Is forced refreshing files creates lags?

Tags: php, jquery

To be sure the user get the latest version of my files, I use something like this

```
$.getScript('scripts/dashboard.js?refresh=<?php echo time();?>');
```

My client report some lags. Is that 'trick' may be the cause? I tried monitoring, and the answer was no. But I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Your browser cannot interprete PHP !

Comment: What is "lags"? Can you define that in specific technical terms? Does it mean that the time there is not changing? That PHP will execute once and once only when the page is rendered. For an automatically updating timestamp you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. Breaking all caches between the client and the resource will introduce delays to re-fetch that resource from its backend storage.

Comment: How did you monitor? Also, by rendering using PHP, you'll always use the same value for `time()` because you're not reloading, so it's useless. About the lags, yes, if you load JS files every time, it will take longer to load; try using script versions instead (naming them with version)

Comment: @tadman An excessive time of reaching/loading files from the server

Comment: "Excessive" is subjective. Can you describe the exact behaviour you're seeing in specific numerical terms? "Constantly refreshing" or "loading every second" is better than "excessive". Remember, the PHP code executes *once* and that time will **not** update client-side. This [`getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) call is run once in the code you're showing here, there's nothing excessive about it.

Comment: @Alfabravo php first, script then. It works

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? `getScript` is not something you'd ordinarily use when `<script>` does the job or `$.ajax` is getting JSON data.

Comment: Ok, there's no JS-related reloading. Still, the question lacks info about the presumed lags

Comment: @tadman Yes ok, for exemple when the client log in, (there's I call the files) after some days of usage, the dashboard.js (for exemple) take around 600~800ms to load. I'm pretty sure the problem is server sided from there, but I may be wrong

Comment: This JavaScript code will run instantaneously. If the server takes 800ms to render the content that's not the fault of this code, it's a server-side issue relating to code we can't see or comment on.

Comment: @tadman Nice, that exactly answer my question :) thanks!